# VPN PPTP connection for ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, routing

Not sure if I should be creating a new post or replying to a very old post. But this is the guide that I followed.

[Failure to connect to PPTP VPN in Ubuntu: VPN plugin failed: 1](https://superuser.com/questions/428136/failure-to-connect-to-pptp-vpn-in-ubuntu-vpn-plugin-failed-1)

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 server so have to setup pptp manually. I know my vpn server is working cos my Windows machines are able to connect and all the traffic gets routed through it.

```
using channel 9
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x5d1a0bd> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xc65ae795> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xc65ae795> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x5d1a0bd> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x5d1a0bd]
rcvd [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xc65ae795]
sent [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x5d1a0bd]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1d <e1a713ac563e9796d19b53a80e508df6>, name = "pptpd"]
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1d <2c1b2fc24ee76a1dcb18ac30712c0c7e0000000000000000d2190880ae45acc1009f0db52a812809120fca16176b409c00>, name = "banz"]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xc65ae795]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1d "S=B3DD9D98BCB681671598BDC4AAF21A94BF3BA081 M=Access granted"]
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [CCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 192.168.5.1>]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 192.168.5.1>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 192.168.5.10>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 192.168.5.10>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 192.168.5.10>]
local  IP address 192.168.5.10
remote IP address 192.168.5.1
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 12796)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 12796), status = 0x0
```

This is my routing table.

```
default         192.168.61.253  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.5.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.61.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
spmental2.info  192.168.61.253  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

The connection gets established but no traffic goes through it.

I'm noticing some errors in syslog.

```
Nov 28 10:52:50 xxx pptp[14050]: anon log[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:414]: buffering packet 69 (expecting 68, lost or reordered)
Nov 28 10:56:20 xxx pptp[14050]: anon log[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:414]: buffering packet 82 (expecting 81, lost or reordered)
Nov 28 10:56:20 xxxx pptp[14050]: anon log[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:414]: buffering packet 83 (expecting 81, lost or reordered)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No surprise it does not work: your routing table is set up as a point-to-point connection to your VPN server, spmental2.info; there are no other routes for anything, neither reaching the network behind the server, nor using the server to reach the Internet.

You can add the route behind the server with the command

```
  sudo route add -net 192.168.5.0/24 dev ppp0
```

If you wish all of your traffic routed through your VPN server, you will need to issue also these two commands:

```
  sudo route delete default gw 192.168.61.253
  sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.5.1 dev ppp0
```

You may try whether this works, but I fear it may not. The reason is that such an incomplete routing table should never have been produced by the automatic scripts in the first place, so I suspect that there is something else fundamentally wrong at play here. If this is indeed the case, I suggest you google a good PPTP guide for your distro, there are many excellent ones around.

Comment: It worked after modifying the routes!

So I need to add it to my /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/vpn file to do it automatically after connecting to vpn?

Comment: Yes. Glad it was that simple.